# to run some controllers in test mode only, for playframework

Tags: playframework

Is it possible to run some **controllers** and **routes** only in test mode?

I need to mock some response when clicking by link. I would create controller and routs that would be available only when I run **play test**.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Mike has indicated, the code from my Blog indeed shows you how to configure your route file, so that only certain routes are available in Dev or Prod mode. So...

```
%{ if (play.mode.isDev()) { }%
GET     /route4                                 Application.noProd
GET     /route5                                 Application.noProd
GET     /route6                                 Application.noProd
%{ } }%
```

However, this will indeed prevent these routes from working in Prod mode, but they will not exclude the controller from being accessed. The reason for this, is that more than likely you will have the following at the bottom of your routes file

```
*       /{controller}/{action}                  {controller}.{action}
```

This means that I can access the `Application.noProd` action using the catch all route, which would be the following URL

```
/application/noprod
```

So. If you want to hide your routes and your controllers, you have a few options.

1. You could remove the catch-all route, so that there is no entry other than the specific routes you have set up. This does mean that you need to specify all your routes for all actions in your routes file.
2. Secondly, you could check for `play.mode.isDev()` in your actions, and call `badRequest()` to prevent access. This would make this much more visible, but may be an unacceptable overhead in coding.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it possible. You can add code to your route file like:

```
%{ if (play.mode.isDev()) { }%
    GET     /route4                                 Application.noProd
    GET     /route5                                 Application.noProd
    GET     /route6                                 Application.noProd
    %{ } }%
```

Everything is explained on this website: http://playframework.wordpress.com/2011/07/15/hidden-features-of-the-play-framework-routes-file/

Answer (score 1):

Another way to hide test controllers and views is to move them to **test** directory.
Just create a controller package in in **test** folder like:

```
public class TestController extends Controller {
    public static void show() {
        renderTemplate("/test/views/Test/show.html");
    }
}
```

So you can keep your catch-all route and your TestController will never be exposed to public in mode other then **test**.

Answer (score 0):

I just successfully set it up like this:

```
%{ if (play.id.equals("test")) { }%
GET     /testme                                         Test.index
%{ } }%
```

so the route will only exist if you run "play test", which is more specific.

Also, I put my controller Test on ../test/controllers/ , so it will not exist in production mode.
Somehow, I had to put my views/Test/index.html inside .../app, because it could not be found inside .../test, which is strange since the controller *is* found under .../test. I could probably make an issue for this, but I won't since Play2 is out a long time already.